# Is Aumann-Serrano risk measure coherent?

Tags: risk

Is the Aumann-Serrano risk measure (Robert J. Aumann, and Roberto Serrano: *An Economic Index of Riskiness*, JPE, Vol. 116 No. 5, October 2008. <[link](https://eml.berkeley.edu/%7Ewebfac/ahn/e208_s07/wp2006-20.pdf)>) [coherent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_risk_measure)? And why yes or no?

Comment: Can you give the definition of the measure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me give it a try: Afaik, the risk measure $R$ is defined such that
$$R: \mathrm{E}_x\left(e^{-x/R}\right)\stackrel{}{=}1$$

One of the requirements for a coherent risk measure is that it is invariant to adding cash. Quoting wiki:

> If $A$ is a deterministic portfolio with guaranteed return $a$, $R(Z+A)=R(Z)-a$

Let's add a cash return $a$ to our normally distributed gamble with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$:

$$
\begin{align}
E(e^{-(x+a)/R})&=e^{-\frac{a+\mu}{R(x+a)}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sigma^2}{R(x+a)^2}}\stackrel{!}{=}1 \\
\Rightarrow R(x+a)&=\frac{\sigma^2}{2(a+\mu)}\neq \frac{\sigma^2}{2\mu}-a=R(x)-a
\end{align}
$$

Assuming I made no mistakes until here, the measure is not translation invariant.